# Automatically extract known file types (eg. zip) using binwalk

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format

This should have been made easy using `binwalk` however I fail to understand what I did wrong with the following syntax:

```
$ wget --content-disposition https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/archive/v2.1.1.zip
$ wget --content-disposition https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/archive/v2.0.1.zip
$ cat binwalk-2.0.1.zip binwalk-2.1.1.zip > full
$ binwalk -r -C output -e full
```

lead to the following:

```
$ ls output/_full.extracted
binwalk-2.1.1/
```

Clearly it is missing the `binwalk-2.0.1` expanded directory. Where did `binwalk-2.0.1` go ?

I need to use the `-r` flag (Delete carved files after extraction), because it generates enormous zip and fill my disk (see [Carved files are often equal in size to the original file](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/issues/153))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnZip` implementation is the cause of your problem. When `binwalk` extracts `full`, the first ZIP actually contains both ZIPs, but `UnZip` only extracts the last one (which is also stored independently in the second ZIP that `binwalk` extracted).

**`binwalk` expects `p7zip`, so install `p7zip` to fix this problem.**

```
$ wget https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/archive/v2.0.1.zip
$ wget https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/archive/v2.1.1.zip
$ mv v2.0.1.zip binwalk-2.0.1.zip
$ mv v2.1.1.zip binwalk-2.1.1.zip
$ cat binwalk-2.0.1.zip binwalk-2.1.1.zip > full
$ ls -l
2255007 binwalk-2.0.1.zip
 288920 binwalk-2.1.1.zip
2543927 full
$ binwalk -r -C output -e full
$ ls -l output/_full.extracted/
2543927 0.zip      # both ZIPs
 288920 22689F.zip # last ZIP
$ mkdir final && unzip output/_full.extracted/'*.zip' -d final/
$ ls -l final/
binwalk-2.1.1                                   # bad
$ rm -r output/ final/                          # cleanup
                                                # install p7zip                                                          
$ binwalk -r -C output -e full
$ ls -l output/_full.extracted/
binwalk-2.0.1
binwalk-2.1.1                                   # good
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `$ apt-cache policy p7zip-full` in your answer ?

Comment: @tibar I am using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) `binwalk @2.1.1` and `p7zip @16.02` on OS X.